# Auth0 Email Whitelist Rule blocks users from Login is too strict

Tags: reactjs, authentication, auth0

I have an auth0 rule which only allows users with my domain like @mybusiness.com to login through auth0 hook in reactjs application.

However, if a user accidentally tries to login with another email domain they don't get in - this is good - but then they cannot even retry with another email as they are 'Unauthorized'. This is bad.

```
  // Access should only be granted to verified users.
  if (!user.email || !user.email_verified) {
    return callback(new UnauthorizedError('Access denied.'));
    //
  }

  const whitelist = ['mybusiness.com']; //authorized domains
  const userHasAccess = whitelist.some(function (domain) {
    const emailSplit = user.email.split('@');
    return emailSplit[emailSplit.length - 1].toLowerCase() === domain;
  });

  if (!userHasAccess) {
    return callback(new UnauthorizedError('Access denied.'));
    //
  }

  return callback(null, user, context);
}
```

I have to go in and delete the user from Auth0 to allow them to try again. My thoughts are to throw a different error but I have tried a few punts but couldn't find any documentation for Auth0 rules. Note* this is a auth0 predefined rule not a custom rule.